# Problem moving layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

Just wondering if anyone ever experiences any problems moving layers? I have set up QGIS in the office and it works brilliantly for everyone apart from one of my colleagues who finds that on odd occassions he cannot move the order of his layers around. No error messages come up but nothing happens when he tries to drag the layers. This only goes away when he restarts his QGIS.

The version of QGIS is 2.8 and we are using Windows 8.

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: which OS? Version of QGis? etc

Comment: I have the problem that I can start moving layers, but quite often when still moving the mouse "drops" and some layers I moved over disappeared, others are selected. Quite random behaviour, sometimes moving works as indented.

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially be down to the two different layer panels:

One is Layer order and the other is Layers:

[image]

Untick the "Control rendering order" in the Layer order panel, which will then allow you to control it through the main Layers panel.

To turn these on and off use the:
View>Panels menu

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, unfortunately on closer inspection of this Layer Order panel, the checkbox is already unchecked, I'm wondering if this could be a bug, or perhaps something to do with the fact that he has 3 monitors? The version of QGIS is 2.8 and we are using Windows 8